# Compare two rows, write comment in third row if match

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google sheet that is collecting the entries from a google form. I have two columns full of email addresses. I need to compare them and if the email from list A is found in list B as well, then I want to write "paid" in a third column, next to the email of list/column B. If the email in list A isn't found in list B then "unpaid" should appear instead.

I'm an absolute beginner and would be very thankful for simple answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use formulas to do this. The formula given below tries to find the match of A2 cell in the B2:B Range with match() formula and if the match is obtained then it add the "paid" string else adds "unpaid"

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B$2:B,0)),"unpaid","paid")
```

this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: thanks very much for the quick answer. It doesn't work for me, I get an error message:
how ca I add an image here?

Comment: I believe the issue is locale (country), Change the ','s in the formula to ';'s and it should work.

Comment: That's it, if I change "," to ";" it does indeed work, thanks very much!

Comment: though this generally works, at some point formulas always give me trouble and don't work well with the script that has to run along. that is why I hope there is a solution to do this just in app script and without formulas.

Comment: you can try doing the same thing with appscript also, just take both the column values in two arrays respectively and try looping through an array to find the element in second array and add the if conditions as given in formula accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [ArrayFormula](https://www.labnol.org/internet/arrayformula-copy-formulas-in-entire-column/29711/).

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A, if(A:A=B:B, "PAID", "UNPAID"),""))
```

The advantage is that when new Google Form submissions are added to the Google Sheet, the cell value will be computed automatically for the new row.

[image]

error here as well:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much as well, sadly error here as well. I think it is because emails are strings and not number values.

Comment: I'd like to try this formula as well and change "," to ";" but whatever I try changing the characters, it will automatically change back from ";" to "," very strange

Comment: is there a way to do this in app script and not with formulas? because the formulas never work well along a script for me.

Comment: would really appreciate at least a hint on how to do this via app script.